# Regex to extract content between css

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

So I'm trying to make it so the I get all the text out of a css class.

For instance,

```
h1 {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

I need to get a string which will contain "font-weight: bold;"

I also need to make sure this doesn't get mixed up with other classes. Basically imagine that was in the middle of a huge css file. How would I get just that class.

(it is ok to ignore things such as h1.blah or variations of h1.)

Comment: Yes... *trying to figure out how you knew that*

Comment: Oh, simple... You tagged that as `nsregularexpression`, for which the tag says it is a class from the Apple developer library :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the RegEx to grab anything inside of a standard h1 declaration. It takes into account spacing and so forth. You probably want more finely-tuned results, but the question lacks the specificity necessary to address the problem further.

`/h1\s*{(.+?)}/m`

Comment: +1, but could be more efficient by using a complemented character class: `/h1\s*{([^}]+)}/m` -- it avoids the use for a lazy quantifier

Comment: Thanks much appreciated, for some reason nsregularexpression doesn't like either one though. it keeps giving me '{NSInvalidValue=/h1\s*{(.+?)}/m}' any ideas?

Comment: Comments and quotes can cause problems.

Comment: the \s was giving me a problem but I escaped the \ and it prints out the proper expression when I log it. However, when I actually send it through the function to create the NSRegularExpression instance it fails.

Comment: You probably need to escape { and }

Comment: yeah it seems the brackets are screwing it up however I can't seem to get it to get the proper result.